# Limit numbers in regular expression

Tags: regex

I am trying to limit number of characters to accept my regular expression from 6 to 30.

I have been trying this as:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9_.]+[@]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_.])*{6,30}$
```

I have tried inputs like `example@gmail.commmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm`

This is not accepting total characters size as 30. but it is checking count after first occurrence of @

Sorry for wrong english

Comment: PLEASE! Do not try to write your own Regex to parse email addresses. The only reliable way to test an email is to try and send to it as the standard allows many character combinations. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Syntax for examples of valid email addresses. If you must validate via a regex see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?=.{6,30}$)([\w.]+@[\w.]+)$
```

Comment: In OP, it seems that `@` is optionnal.

Comment: @M42: True I also noticed that but validating an email I guess `@` shouldn't be optional (just applied my own interpretation)

Comment: True, we can guess he wants to validate an email, but who knows?

Comment: @user3066213: Fell free to change regex to: `^(?=.{6,30}$)([\w.]+@?[\w.]*)$` If `@` is optional.

Comment: In my opinion, he made the `@` optional only because it is inside a repeated group.

Comment: yes anubhava here @ is optional.Thanks a lot for your replies. I changed my regular expression now.It is working fine.Thanku